# Do demonyms largely depend upon the historical period in which they originate?

Tags: etymology, history, demonyms

A friend of mine told me English demonyms, words that identify people from a particular place (Roman, Japanese, Dutch etc.), largely depend upon the historical period in which the term originates. However, looking at the [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym), it's difficult for me to see a specific historical pattern.
Is there anyone here who knows anything about how history has influenced the use of English demonyms? Can we associate a particular demonym with a certain time in history?

Sorry for the vague question. Any insight would be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 3):

Your friend sounds like one who was once described by Josh Billings:

> **"It ain't ignorance causes so much trouble; it's folks knowing so much that ain't so."**

While it may be argued that demonyms reflect the time, place and culture of the people who coined them, most such words have been formed by tacking a suffix, whose origin is typically Greek or Roman (imported by way of French, Italian, or something else.)

Browse for yourself at

Online Etymology Dictionary. Douglas Harper, Historian. 12 Apr. 2016. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

> English demonyms, largely depend upon the historical period in which the term originates.

This is close to a truism.

It is a truth universally acknowledged, that an apt and acceptable demonym must be in search of a demos and must await a town, state, or country, etc., to be established or discovered.

Once this is achieved, the demonym must then await a **need** for a demonym: We might see how a hamlet in God’s blind spot may never achieve this, whereas the people of a warlike region, ruling state, or of great economic power will be given several demonyms depending on whose side you are.

And once the need is established, there will be several claimants and one will win out: “Cometh the time, cometh the demonym.”

And thus demonyms, like all words, are “of their time.”

Comment: This may be an account of when a demonym comes into being, but it doesn't answer whether demonyms that came into being at one time are formed in a different way from demonyms that came into being at a different time, which seems to be what the OP was asking about. For example, one can find among the old, well-established demonyms some that are altogether different from the names that the people in question use for themselves, while the demonyms that entered the circulation recently tend to closely follow the endonyms; the OP seems curious whether anything more precise can be said about that.

Comment: @jsw29 The question is *"Can we associate a particular demonym with a certain time in history?"* My answer is *“Cometh the time, cometh the demonym.” And thus demonyms, like all words, are “of their time.”* If the OP wants to be given a demonym that we know for certain arose at a particular time, they should make that clear.